# Asking how to make combined query with name and date

Tags: google-sheets

this is my first post here.
I'm new to google sheet and this is the first time I'm using query.
I already watched some tutorials on youtube, but i'm having a hard time how to combine query between name and dates (start and end date). I only managed to make how to search name query

Can someone help me how to make this combined query? Thank you so much

The file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AzldUqBoXz_tDZB8EppB7Kh2l32UtMmrXXonOxcCYDA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below `QUERY()` function. See your sheet.

```
=QUERY(Database!A:H;"select * where D='" &B4 & "' and E>= date '" &TEXT(E4;"yyyy-mm-dd")& "' and E<= date '" & TEXT(G4;"yyyy-mm-dd")& "'")
```

[image]